# Can drop=FALSE be passed to $?

Tags: r, dollar-sign

I tried  `` `$`(mtcars,cyl,drop=FALSE) ``, but this threw an error. I know that in practice you would use `[` or `[[` instead, but I'm curious, can `drop=FALSE` be passed to `$`?

Comment: @MrFlick Might as well post that as an answer. If it's plain and simply impossible, then so be it. I probably should've checked the `formals` of `$`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$` function doesn't have a `drop=` parameter. While they are used for similar things, the `$` function is distinct from the `[` function which does have a `drop=` parameter.

I'm assuming that you are only interested in the case for using `$` with data.frames, but there's actually no special data.frame method for `$`, it just treats the data.frame like a list. And `drop=` wouldn't make as much sense in the case of a generic list.